# How to achieve focus blur effect on a image in android?

Tags: android

I want to blur a part of an image by selection some portion except the focused area.
The focused area is predefined  ,lets say I want to blur only about 30% from bottom, rest of the image remained original.

I tried and tweaked libraries on blur image, but could not achieve the result required.

I want the effect on these images. These are from Focus Effect app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dumplingsandwich.focuseffect&hl=en

[image]

[image]

Comment: you could crop the selected area, apply the blur, and then reapply the crop. To blur the image you can use RenderScript

Comment: I thought about this. So i need to crop the image first, blur it and then place it again on the same place and create a full bitmap consisting of the blur image and the not blur image part. Not quite efficient way